# Py-spy: Is it possible to get the output file format as csv or xls or txt for py-spy speedscope format

Tags: python, performance, deep-learning, profiler, hpc

**Aim:  Trying to analyze computational energy consumed in Deep learning model on HPC, and want to compare timesteps for processes in both profilers( energy profiler(Perun) and Py-spy speedscope.**

Background: Energy profiler [Perun](https://pypi.org/project/perun/) has output file format as a csv file by which I get the energy consumed with each time step. I used Py-spy speedscope to understand the exact time line of the processes. I run both, Pyspy and Perun together, and I want to match both of the profilers using same format like csv, so that  I can exactly understand which part of the code( for eg,. backprop which has gradient and update weights consumes high energy) consumes how much energy by matching  the time on the timeline iwth py-spy sppedscope.

These two images show snip form pyspy and perun(in csv) , I tired one to one mapping but it not really feasible.
[This image shoes the speedscope snip for 4.5 sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdSPt.png) 
[This image shows the Energy consumption at 4.5 sec with perun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgMMK.png)

By this commmand I run two profilers concurrently for the script transformer.py

is there a possible way to get speedscope output in CSV format?

```
 py-spy record --rate 500 --format speedscope --output profile.speedscope.json -- python3.9 transformer.py & 
 ~/.local/bin/perun --format hdf5 --sampling_rate 0.5 monitor transformer.py  &
```

I tried one to one mapping from speedscope timeline to energy consumption timeline generate by Perun, but it is not feasible to do one to one mapping.

1. How should I compare both profilers on timeline.
2. is it possible to have a csv format output for pyspy speedscope.

Comment: I advise you not to use software tools to measure the energy consumption. They tends to be *unreliable*. For exemple, they often do not care about what instructions are actually used although it can strongly impact the energy consumption (SIMD vs scalar, occupancy, cache accesses, etc.). They can miss the consumption of *data transfers* (which is becoming more and more critical over time -- especially on HPC machines). Some assume the power consumption is linear to the CPU/GPU usage which is completely wrong. Electrical tools are hard to use on HPC machines, but far more reliable.

Comment: Perun [link](https://github.com/Helmholtz-AI-Energy/perun) 
 taps the sensors on the register which tells about the amount of energy consumed. Basically it is reading the hardware electrical tools. How should I tackle this issue now?


PS:  Also I have tried to reduce the redundenc. Moreover the backend in is in CUDA , so i have alos profiled the memory transfer in L1,l2 caches and main memory, so those factors have been almost been similar across muliple experiments. This code is in numpy so I have taken care to reduce as much redundency as possible.